Chaos Flesh skeletal binding not working properly
I’m working on a medical VR simulation in Unreal Engine 5, using Chaos Flesh to create a soft-body-like structure for a human mesh. The mesh includes an esophagus, and I need skeletal binding to hold the flesh in place.
However, after performing the skeletal binding, the mesh looks heavily deformed, almost like a “Venom” effect with irregular, exaggerated distortions. This deformation persists even after rechecking the skeletal setup and mesh properties.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue with Chaos Flesh? How can I resolve this while maintaining proper skeletal binding?
Steps I’ve Tried:
1.Verified different types of skeletal mesh.
2.Adjusted Chaos Flesh parameters (e.g., solver iterations, stiffness, and damping).
Specifications:
Unreal Engine Version: 5.4
Chaos Flesh NumCell Count: 100
I’d appreciate any guidance or suggestions to fix this deformation issue.

Can you show an example of this "venom" distortion you're observing?

Before Binding:
The mesh looks fine in its initial state, with no visible issues.
After Binding:
Once the skeletal binding is applied, the mesh deforms significantly, creating irregular and exaggerated distortions. It looks almost as though the mesh is being "pulled" in random directions, with spikes and gaps appearing unexpectedly.
